# How Documentum ACL and Groups are connected to each other?

Tags: acl, documentum

ACL are the access list which defines who can access a folder, While a group defines a collection of similar user access.

Can anyone please share how does folder, group and ACL are connected. Can a group have more than one ACL and vice-versa?

Need a little explanation as I am new to Documentum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ACL are the access list which defines who can access a object (folder, content object, process, etc.)
- group defines a collection of users or groups
- ACL have two built in entries (dm_owner or creator, dm_world or eveyone) and N additional entries group or users
- group cannot *have* ACL but more than one ACL can have the same group (one group/user per ACL)

Please, be more specific about your questions. ;)

Comment: Actually I was not sure what do both things does. That's why wasn't specific. Anyways thanks

Comment: Basically ACL defines which groups have which type of access on that object. Right?

Comment: yes. more correctly said: to all objects that have that specific ACL applied to them.